# Why is my cloudinary image upload slower in nodejs and reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

It is my first time of trying to use cloudinary and multer to upload and store images for my blog application.
Initially, I was storing the images locally using multer and saved the image url in mongodb. Now, I store the images in cloudinary and save the url in database.

I noticed that the cloudinary option is a bit slower compared to saving locally. Is there a workaround this?

Here is my nodecode:

```
app.post("/api/v1/upload", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) =>{

try {
    const fileStr = req.file.path
 
    if(!fileStr){
          return res.status(500).json( 'No image found');
    }
    const uploadResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(fileStr, {
        upload_preset: 'nodeblog',
    });
   fs.unlinkSync(fileStr)
    const result = {
        url: uploadResponse.secure_url,
        publicId: uploadResponse.public_id
    }
   return res.status(200).json(result)
   
    
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ err: 'Something went wrong' });
   
}
 

});
```

After image has uploaded successfully, I simply deleted it locally.